# Reload JFrame with JLabel

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel, reload

I have a `Jframe` which contains a `JLabel` which I use to display an image as the background of the `Jframe`.  The path to that image is a `JavaBean` that is changing constantly, this is controlled by an another class file.  I need the `JFrame` to reload every second to keep the `JLabel` image up to date.

I have looked into using the timer to refresh the `JFrame` but I am not sure how to implement it .

I am sorry I cannot post any attempts I have made as I can't really figure out how to use the time to reload a `JFrame`.

Thanks

Comment: Polling is an inefficient way to keep the frame up to date.  Have you considered passing the frame's Graphics reference to whatever is updating the image and having it do the repainting from there?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are proposing but the Javabean is being updated as I can print out the bean but the Jlabel path needs to be updated regularly.  I simply use a an impracticable endless loop to check the print out of the bean.

Comment: I think you'll want to do something like jlabel.getGraphics(), and pass the Graphics instance that actually does the painting over to the Image java bean.  When the bean gets updated, call graphics.drawImage(...) right there.